# Copy Constructor for a linked list with self-referential pointers

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, c++11, linked-list

I came across a coding challenge that looked something like this (recreating from memory, sorry)

> Suppose you have the following interface for a linked list.  Implement an efficient and correct copy constructor.
>
> ```
> template <typename T>
> class SillyLinkedList {
>   public:
>     SillyLinkedList();
>     SillyLinkedList(const SillyLinkedList<T>& rhs);
>     ~SillyLinkedList();
>     void push_back(const T& value);
>   private:
>       struct Node;
>
>       Node* head_;
>       std::size_t size_;
>
>       struct Node {
>         /// The next node in the linked list
>         Node* next_;
>         /// A random node in the linked list
>         Node* random_;
>         T value_;
>       };
> };
> ```

I was allowed to assume that the other functions were implemented as well as provide additional member functions as needed, and came up with this.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

static std::mt19937 rng(std::random_device{}());

template <typename T>
class SillyLinkedList {
  public:
    SillyLinkedList() : head_(nullptr), size_(0) {}
    SillyLinkedList(const SillyLinkedList<T>& rhs);

    ~SillyLinkedList() {
        Node* current = head_;
        while (current) {
            Node* next = current->next_;
            delete current;
            current = next;
        }
    }

    void push_back(const T& value) {
        ++size_;
        if (size_ == 1) {
            std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t>d(0, 1);
            head_ = new Node{nullptr, nullptr, T(value)};
            head_->random_ = d(rng) == 0 ? head_ : nullptr;
        } else {
            Node* current = head_;
            while (current->next_ != nullptr) {
                current = current->next_;
            }

            std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t> d(0, size_-1);
            size_t index = d(rng);
            Node* random = head_;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < index; ++i) {
                random = random->next_;
            }

            current->next_ = new Node{nullptr, random, T(value)};
        }
    }

    template <typename V>
    friend
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const SillyLinkedList<V>& rhs);

  private:
    struct Node;

    Node* head_;
    std::size_t size_;

    struct Node {
        /// The next node in the linked list
        Node* next_;

        /// A random node in the linked list (may be "end" == nullptr)
        Node* random_;
        T value_;
    };
};

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const SillyLinkedList<T>& rhs) {
    using NodeType = typename SillyLinkedList<T>::Node;
    NodeType* current = rhs.head_;

    while (current != nullptr) {
        out << " Location: " << current << " Random: " << current->random_ << std::endl;
        current = current->next_;
    }
    return out;
}

template <typename T>
SillyLinkedList<T>::SillyLinkedList(const SillyLinkedList<T>& rhs) : head_(nullptr), size_(0) {
    if (rhs.size_ != 0) {
        std::unordered_map<Node*, Node*> nodePositions;
        Node* rhsCurr = rhs.head_;
        head_ = new Node;
        Node* current = head_;

        nodePositions.insert(std::make_pair(nullptr, nullptr));

        while (rhsCurr != nullptr) {
            nodePositions.insert(std::make_pair(rhsCurr, current));
            current->value_ = (rhsCurr->value_);
            current->random_ = rhsCurr->random_;
            current->next_ = rhsCurr->next_ == nullptr ? nullptr : new Node;
            current = current->next_;
            rhsCurr = rhsCurr->next_;
            ++size_;
        }

        current = head_;
        while (current != nullptr) {
            current->random_ = std::get<1>(*nodePositions.find(current->random_));
            current = current->next_;
        }
    }
}


int main() {
    SillyLinkedList<int> l;
    for (int i = 0; i < 31; ++i) {
        l.push_back(1 << i);
    }
    SillyLinkedList<int> l2 = l;
    std::cout << l << std::endl;
    std::cout << l2 << std::endl;
}
```

I'd appreciate feedback on any part of the code, however, in particular, I'd appreciate a look at the copy constructor.  It's correct (as far as I can tell), but I'm not sure how clear it is what I'm doing, or if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The copy constructor looks correct and efficient, except that with the given implementation, you can save the second iteration through the nodes, as `rhsCurr->random_` is guaranteed to point to a node already in `nodePositions` (`push_back` always assigns `random_` to a node already in the list and there's no other code that removes nodes or reassign's a node's `random_` member). I would also replace `std::get<1>(*nodePositions.find(current->random_))` with `nodePositions.at(current->random_)`, which is more straightforward and will not throw in this case.

I don't really like your assignment of `random_` in `push_back`; for the first node, you have a 50-50 chance of pointing to itself or "end", but every other node has no chance of pointing to itself. No node points to a later node in the list. An alternative is to use an `unordered_map` as in the copy constructor, and to re-assign `random_` for every node each time the list is modified, with a uniform distribution over each node + "end".

Answer (score 1):

- An immediate problem is an that `rhs` may loop, so

  ```
      while (rhsCurr != nullptr) {
  ```

is not enough. You need some sort of loop detection. Maybe,

```
        while (size_ != rsh.size_)
```

would suffice.

- A dummy node technique is always recommended:

  ```
      Node dummy;
      Node * current = &dummy;
      while (...) {
          current->next = new Node(rhsCurr);
          current = current->next;
          nodePosition.insert(...);
          rhsCurr = rhsCurr->next;
          ...
      }
  ```

  just to avoid `current->next_ = rhsCurr->next_ == nullptr ? nullptr : new Node;` which IMHO is pretty ugly.

Comment: rhs can't loop with this implementation of `push_back`, or with any reasonable implementation of it. Users of the class have no access to `Node` or any node's `next_` member, so the class can maintain the invariant that its nodes don't loop.

Comment: @ruds Do you trust every input you are given?

Comment: I trust the invariants of my own code. The only way loop detection would be necessary is if someone else created a memory buffer, twiddled the bits, cast it to a `SillyLinkedList`, and then called the copy constructor. This is not something worth defending against.